# Read transparent images as white background scikit-image python

Tags: python, scikit-image, alpha-transparency

I've a transparent image (4 channels) where the 4th channel is alpha channel.
I want to read the image using `skimage.io.imread()` method. But if I set `pilmode=rgb`, then the transparent part becomes black, but I want it to be white. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```py
import skimage.color
import skimage.io

image = skimage.io.imread('res/images/image.png')
image = skimage.color.rgba2rgb(image)
```